# Debugging all HTTP[S] on node.js

Tags: node.js, macos, http, azure, proxy

I'm having fits accomplishing something and after scouring google & SO, throwing my hands up after a few days. Trying to do something that I think is pretty common: debug / examine all HTTP traffic while developing a node.js app.

In Windows it is as simple as firing up Fiddler and I can see *all* HTTP & HTTPS traffic from all processes. But I've switched platforms over to OSX and trying to make the same work.

I've tried using Charles & MITMPROXY, but all I'm seeing is the traffic to, with the response, my node.js app. My node.js app is calling external services, some using the popular [request](https://npmjs.org/package/request) package (which I have seen how to set that up) but also using other packages, like [azure-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage). What's troubling me is I can't get any of the debugging proxies to show me at the azure-storage package is sending / receiving to the endpoints they are calling.

Conceptually I think I get it... I have to tell these different things (like node.js, request & azure-storage) to go through the proxy each of these tools uses... but how can you do that without modifying their source? Can't, like how Fiddler works on Windows, you do something to "all traffic goes through this proxy"?

I'd use Fiddler on OSX but it is currently not working with no ETA in sight after talking to Telerik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem I was having is what I thought... in my specific instance the module that I was using to access Azure storage was not using the default proxy. I found a package (**[global-tunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-tunnel**) that hijacked everything that used the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package to control it going through a proxy. Now I saw stuff show up in the HTTP debuggers I was using.

The problem now is when I am trying to reach an HTTPS endpoint... using something like Charles, it used it's own SSL cert which wasn't trusted by Azure so the connections were refused. Back to the drawing board...